# How to get total CPU % and Memory% usage on Ubuntu in using .NET core application

Tags: system

Even **PerformanceCounter** is supported in .NET core, but it is not supported on the Ubuntu OS, so is there any way to get the **system overall** CPU and memory usage in a .NET core application (like the task manager shows in Windows)?

Comment: You have not even said what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @David The version is 20.04

Comment: Have you tried the [Universe.CpuUsage NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Universe.CpuUsage/)? I see you've asked some follow-up questions for this sort of functionality on StackOverflow as well. Perhaps they can offer something more specific.